# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion

Last year around Christmas time [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) had an awesome promotion in which they awarded hats for gravatars for completing basic tasks around the site. If you don't remember it, here is a [link](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) the promo from last year (and [another!](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/)).

[image: hats]

This year, SE is planning to run it for *everyone*.

But to get this awesome hat promotion we have to **opt in**. That means acting on this meta post, whether that's voting it up, answering in the affirmative, positive comments and/or just directing positive energy this direction.

This promotion is **optional** for sites, and/or individual users. If the users of this site *do not* want this in general feel free to voice that opinion. We can opt out of the promotion. Individual users will be able to opt out as well (they will be provided with an "I hate Hats" link to opt out).

Please let us know what you think as this is your site not ours.

<sub>[This post is based on Wax Eagle's template from C.SE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1420/do-you-like-hats)</sub>

Comment: I think it's a fun idea. Why not give it a go?

Comment: Yup defo, I'd be in for one of those :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered to SE that we opt in and will participate in the Hat Dash.